# How can you merge multiple table data structures into one table result structure?

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary

Suppose I have two query results stored in two different .csv files (1.csv, 2.csv), the data looks like this:

- 1.csv:

[image]

- 2.csv

[image]

dim1 & dim2 will be **present** in every query table result, the fields can be different.

**How can I get a result that looks like this ?**

- result

[image]

**The fields are uniquely concatenated in the result table, and the rows are grouped by the key (dim1 and dim2)**

I've used a `List<List<string>>` to represent each table result:

```
public static List<List<string>> R1 { get; } = new List<List<string>>
    {
        new List<string> {"dim1", "dim2", "field1"},
        new List<string> {"2", "wwa", "3"},
        new List<string> {"1", "arr", "6"}
    };

    public static List<List<string>> R2 { get; } = new List<List<string>>
    {
        new List<string> {"dim1", "dim2", "field2", "field3"},
        new List<string> {"2", "jaja", "1000", "2"},
        new List<string> {"3", "wwa", "1000", "3"},
        new List<string> {"1", "arr", "2000", "4"}
    };
```

**And I went with the following strategy:**

```
var keys = 2;
        var results = new List<List<string>>();

        foreach (var r1 in R1)
        {
            var range = r1.GetRange(0, keys);
            var hash = range.GetKey();
            var found = false;

            var row = new List<string>();
            foreach (var r2 in R2)
            {
                if (r2.GetRange(0, keys).GetKey() == hash)
                {
                    row.AddRange(range);
                    row.AddRange(r1.GetRange(keys, r1.Count - keys));
                    row.AddRange(r2.GetRange(keys, r2.Count - keys));
                    results.Add(row);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                row.AddRange(r1);
                R2[0].GetRange(keys, R2[0].Count - keys).ForEach(e => row.Add(null));
                results.Add(row);
            }
        }

        foreach (var r2 in R2)
        {
            var range = r2.GetRange(0, keys);
            var hash = range.GetKey();
            var found = false;

            var row = new List<string>();
            foreach (var r in results)
            {
                if (r.GetRange(0, keys).GetKey() == hash)
                    found = true;
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                row.AddRange(range);
                R1[0].GetRange(keys, R1[0].Count - keys).ForEach(e => row.Add(null));
                row.AddRange(r2.GetRange(keys, r2.Count - keys));
                results.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I have 2xN^2 complexity and I think there should be a better solution to generate the new `List<List<string>>` that suits the above example.

Comment: Have you looked into some ETL frameworks which support join operations?

Comment: this needs to be done in memory because the columns are dynamic, dim1, dim2 can be different for other queries, and there are scenarios where you can have one or more dimensions as grouping key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A List join can be done  with as follows

```
 private void JoinList(List<List<string>> listToJoin, int keysNumber, int paddingAfterKeys = 0)
    {
        // you need the padding if an element is found only in the second list
        // this is a list that will be added to the result 
        var paddingList = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < paddingAfterKeys; i++)
        {
            // feel free to change it to null or what value fit your solution
            paddingList.Add("0");
        }
        foreach (var t in listToJoin)
        {
            // create a key
            var keyString = string.Join(',', t.Take(keysNumber));
            if (result.TryGetValue(keyString, out var fieldsList))
            {
                // if the key already exist just add the values except the keys values this way you won't get duplicate keys
                fieldsList.AddRange(t.Skip(keysNumber));
            }
            else
            {
                // get the keys, pad the list if needed and the rest of the keys
                fieldsList = t.Take(keysNumber).ToList();
                fieldsList.AddRange(paddingList);
                fieldsList.AddRange(t.Skip(keysNumber));
                // add new key to the dictionary and set the value in my program the result was a private variable of the class for the ease of use.
                result[keyString] = fieldsList;
            }
        }
    }
```

If the keys are not the first you can do an list which keeps the indexes and get the keys from index.

To orchestrate this you will need something like this:

```
public void ProcessLists()
    {
       const int keysNumber = 2;
       var totalLength = R1[0].Count + R2[0].Count - keysNumber;
       // add first list to dictionary
       JoinList(R1, keysNumber);
       var paddingAfterKeys = R1[0].Count - keysNumber;
       // add the second list to dictionary and add padding if a key was not found in dictionary
       JoinList(R2, keysNumber, paddingAfterKeys);

       // add padding to the end if a key was found in first list but not in second
       paddingAfterKeys = R2[0].Count - keysNumber;

       var paddingList = new List<string>();
       for (var i = 0; i < paddingAfterKeys; i++)
       {
           paddingList.Add("0");
       }
       foreach (var keyValuePair in result.Where(x => x.Value.Count < totalLength))
       {
          keyValuePair.Value.AddRange(paddingList);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create strongly typed objects modeled after your CSV records, both the input record and your final output record.Then use LINQ to combine your records.

Here is a small working example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<CsvOne> InitCsvOne()
        {
            //mock pulling in data
            List<CsvOne> csv = new List<CsvOne>
        {
            new CsvOne { dim1 = 2,dim2 = "wwa", field1 =3 },
            new CsvOne { dim1 = 1, dim2 = "arr", field1 = 6}
        };
            return csv;
        }
        public static List<CsvTwo> InitCsvTwo()
        {
            //mock pulling in data
            List<CsvTwo> csv = new List<CsvTwo>
        {
            new CsvTwo { dim1 = 2,dim2 = "jaja", field2 = 1000, field3 =2 },
            new CsvTwo { dim1 = 3, dim2 = "waa", field2 = 1000, field3 = 3 },
            new CsvTwo { dim1 = 1, dim2 = "arr", field2 = 2000, field3 = 4},
        };
            return csv;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var csvOne = InitCsvOne();
            var csvTwo = InitCsvTwo();
            var csvThree = new List<CsvThree>();
            //get the ball rolling with csv one
            csvOne.ForEach(record =>csvThree.Add(new CsvThree(record)));
            //now either match up one with two or add with field1 being 0
            //if we already have a matching dim1 and dim2, lets update the two new fields.
            //note that we do not add another one if there are two the same
            csvTwo.ForEach(record =>
           {  
               if (csvThree.Any(t => (t.dim1 == record.dim1 && t.dim2 == record.dim2)))
                   {
                       //combine the match with fields 2 and 3
                       var theMatch = csvThree.FirstOrDefault(t => (t.dim1 == record.dim1 && t.dim2 == record.dim2)); 
                       theMatch.field2 = record.field2;
                       theMatch.field3 = record.field3;
                   }
                   else //add this new record to the list
                   {
                       csvThree.Add(new CsvThree(record));
                   }
            });
            csvThree = csvThree.OrderBy(t => t.dim1).ThenBy(t=>t.dim2).ToList(); //or whatever you want
            //check it 
            Console.WriteLine($"Csv One Records");
            Console.WriteLine($" dim1|dim2|field1");
            csvOne.ForEach(record =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(record.ToString());
            });
            Console.WriteLine($"Csv Two Records");
             Console.WriteLine($"dim1|dim2|field2|field3");
            csvTwo.ForEach(record =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(record.ToString());
            });
            Console.WriteLine($"Csv Three Records");
            Console.WriteLine($"dim1|dim2|field1|field2|field3");
            csvThree.ForEach(record =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(record.ToString());
            });
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            var wait = Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public abstract class dim
    { 
        public int dim1 { get; set; }
        public string dim2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class CsvOne:dim
    {
        public int field1 { get; set; }
        public CsvOne()
        {
            field1 = 0;
        } 
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{dim1}  |{dim2}|{field1}";
        }
    }
    public class CsvTwo:dim
    {
        public int field2 { get; set; }
        public int field3 { get; set; }
        public CsvTwo()
        {
            field2 = field3 = 0;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{dim1}  |{dim2}|{field2}|{field3}";
        }
    }
    public class CsvThree : dim
    {
        public int field1 { get; set; }
        public int field2 { get; set; }
        public int field3 { get; set; }
        public CsvThree()
        {
            field1 = field2 = field3 = 0;
        }
        public CsvThree(CsvOne value)
        {
            field1 = field2 = field3 = 0;
            dim1 = value.dim1;
            dim2 = value.dim2;
            field1 = value.field1;
        }
        public CsvThree(CsvTwo value)
        {
            field1 = field2 = field3 = 0;
            dim1 = value.dim1;
            dim2 = value.dim2;
            field2 = value.field2;
            field3 = value.field3;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{dim1}  |{dim2}|{field1}|{field2}|{field3}";
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Csv One Records
 dim1|dim2|field1
2  |wwa|3
1  |arr|6
Csv Two Records
dim1|dim2|field2|field3
2  |jaja|1000|2
3  |waa|1000|3
1  |arr|2000|4
Csv Three Records
dim1|dim2|field1|field2|field3
1  |arr|6|2000|4
2  |jaja|0|1000|2
2  |wwa|3|0|0
3  |waa|0|1000|3
Press any key to exit...
```